# Core Data updating all "index" property (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a property (NSNumber) in core data called "boardIndex" in the entity "Task".  Each boardIndex is unique, meaning there cannot be two tasks with boardIndex 3.

When I update a boardIndex, say from 3 to 5, I need to update all the other entities "boardIndex" property in Core Data by incrementing or decrementing by 1 (or doing nothing).  For instance, the task whose boardIndex was 4 is now 3, the task whose boardIndex was 5 is now 4, and the boardIndex who was 3 is now 5; similar to how an indexPath works in a tableView.

What is the best practice for doing this?  I read about "Core Spotlight" but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go.  Any help would be great.

Code if it helps:

```
//This only updates one task, how to update other tasks?
task?.boardIndex = childIndexPath?.row as NSNumber?
DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I update a boardIndex, say from 3 to 5, I need to update all the other entities "boardIndex" property in Core Data by incrementing or decrementing by 1 (or doing nothing).

The best way to do that would be to use a data structure that maintains the order of the tasks for you. The way to do that with Core Data is to use an ordered to-many property.

Create a separate entity to hold the list of tasks. For example, you might have a `Board` entity that has a to-many, ordered relationship to `Task`. That ordered relationship will be represented by an [`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset) object to which you can add your tasks.

> I read about "Core Spotlight" but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go.

That's a completely different kind of indexing -- Spotlight lets the user search through the data on their device, and Core Spotlight lets you include your app's data in the search.

Comment: Hey Caleb, sorry for the delay.  I believe this is the answer I need.  Thank you!